# Keyboard layout popup. XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to demonstrate keyboard layout (like pop-up) during switching language? I am using Xubuntu.

In macOS it looks like follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`xfce4-xkb-plugin` can show you all installed keyboard layouts if you install more than two.  Not on the center of the screen though.  You'll be able to see them under the country flag when you click on it.

On Xubuntu it's preinstalled normally, so the only thing you have to do is add it to a panel.  If it's not installed, use `sudo apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin` to install it and then add it to a panel.

Comment: I am asking about showing notification during layout change. I want to use auto-hiding for panel but cant w/o such feature.